# Using Full-Text Search in Linq / ODataController

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, odata

I am working on an application which serves data via OData. I am using ASP.Net and ODataControllers querying via EF -- the data is backed by a SQLServer database.

On the front-end website which visualizes this data, the user can search results -- a $filter is dynamically created on the front end and an OData request is sent (allowing server-side filtering).

On the database table backing the data which is eventually served via OData, full-text search is enabled, but it appears in the pipeline OData filter -> Linq query -> SQL query, a LIKE search is used instead of the full-text Contains() method.

Is there any way that anyone knows of to make this use the full-text capabilities in a reasonably elegant way?

Presumably I can do a lot of fumbling about with a custom `IODataPathHandler` and / or `IODataPathTemplateHandler` and / or some other things to intercept the points in the pipeline, but I'd rather try to avoid that if possible.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

OData's `contains` function is meant to perform a simple substring match. The OData spec defines the `$search` query option for full-text search, but Web API does not currently support `$search`. (There is an [open issue](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/155).)

Your best bet is probably a custom query option (e.g., `/Customers?fulltextsearch=contains(Name, 'Arianne')`), but you'll have to write all of the code to parse the option, etc.

If you are determined to map OData `contains` to T-SQL `CONTAINS`, then you will need to intercept the translation done by Linq to Entities. Look at the source code for the existing [ContainsTranslator](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Relational/Query/ExpressionTranslators/ContainsTranslator.cs) and work backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [interceptor](http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch) and a custom [EnableQueryAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.enablequeryattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) for that purpose:

1. Define a `FtsInterceptor` class as described in the article and add it to your context - `DbInterception.Add(new FtsInterceptor())`.
2. Define a subclass of the `EnableQueryAttribute` class and override the `ApplyQuery` method adding *FullTextPrefix* (-FTSPREFIX-) for all parameters of the OData [contains](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398117) function:

   ```
   public class FullTextSearchAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
   {
       public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
       {
           if (queryOptions.Filter == null)
              return queryOptions.ApplyTo(queryable);

           const string pattern = "contains\\([%20]*[^%27]*[%20]*,[%20]*%27(?<Value>[^%27]*)";

           var matchEvaluator = new MatchEvaluator(match =>
           {
               var value = match.Groups["Value"].Value;

               return match.Value.Replace($"%27{value}", $"%27-FTSPREFIX-{value}");
           });

           var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, 
                     Regex.Replace(queryOptions.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri,
                         pattern,
                         matchEvaluator,
                         RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

           return new ODataQueryOptions(queryOptions.Context, request).ApplyTo(queryable);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use the attribute in your code:

   ```
   [FullTextSearchAttribute]
   public IQueryable<YourDomainClass> Get()
   {
       //Query 
   }
   ```