# Entity Framework converts Contains to SQL LIKE or CHARINDEX

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I am using an OData endpoint to retrieve data from a SQL Database. I have a C# controller where Entity Framework converts the query to SQL. I need to use the SQL CONTAINS as I am going against a Full Text Catalogue. However, Entity Framework seems to be converting the `CONTAINS` to `LIKE` or `CHARINDEX`. This makes the search very slow and defeats the purpose of having a Full Text Catalogue. Is there a way around this?

**C# Controller:**

```
    [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = All)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IQueryable<Events>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [ODataRoute("LogEvents")]
    public IQueryable<Events> GetEvents()
    {
        return _dbContext.Events.AsNoTracking();
    }
```

**Example Query:**

```
http://localhost:4000/api/Events?$filter=(contains(tolower(message),'cache'))
```

**From the trace logs I noticed that Entity Framework executes the following commands:**

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command|YJ|17244|13|Creating DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader'
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command|YJ|17244|13|Opening connection to database 'LocalDB' on server 'sql-dev'
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command|YJ|17244|13|Opened connection to database 'LocalDB' on server 'sql-dev'
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command|YJ|17244|13|Executing DbCommand

WHERE ((@__TypedProperty_0 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__TypedProperty_0, LOWER([l].[Message])) > 0))
```

Comment: ? You want your API to accept and process raw SQL? That doesn't sound very secure... And please show a [mcve]

Comment: `DbFunctions.Contains`. You don't show how the OData gets converted, so it's not clear if (and how) the translation needs to change to make this possible.

Comment: You might need to use an interceptor, as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335117/using-full-text-search-in-linq-odatacontroller

Comment: You can write interceptor like suggested in previous comment, but here we have to correct Expression Tree. If you write small sample application I can support in writing such correction.